# How do you add a package install requirement on python to upload my package to PyPi?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

So what i mean by the title is like this, I'm gonna create a python package and it needs pygame for my package to work, but I can't figure out how do you add that in setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    install_reqs=[
        "pygame",
    ],
    ...
)
```

I change **install_reqs** into???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`install_requires`.

See documentation of the [setup function](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/keywords.html?highlight=setup)

Comment: Tysm! This help alot